# How to retrieve rows from a specific discriminator in EF 6.1.3?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, tph

I'm using TPH approach in my code-first model, the base class is of type `WItem` and the derived is `BItem`, I want to retrieve all the WItems rows only, so I made this

```
return View(db.WItems.OfType<WItem>().ToList());
```

but I still get all the rows `WHERE [Extent1].[Discriminator] IN (N'BItem',N'WItem')}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fellow from Quora suggested this:

```
db.WItems.Where(s => !(s is BItem));
```

It works as I hoped.